# Issue with embedded text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

We are running SQL Server 2016 and Visual Studio 2017 and are trying to import a sample file that has extra text qualifiers inside the data. It previews ok but during runtime, it errors out on record# 2 because - Error 0xc0202055: Data Flow Task 1: The column delimiter for column ""COLUMN1"" was not found.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

| "COLUMN1" | "COLUMN2" |
| --- | --- |
| "KEVIN THOMAS" | "123 Main Street" |
| "GEORGE "Geo" LEWIS" | "345 Tree Line Ave" |

I thought this issue was fixed in SQL Server 2016.

I tried using SSMS import wizard and Visual Studio 2017 and get the same errors.

Comment: How are you importing this data? You've tagged SSIS, which suggests with a data flow task with a flat file source as the connection manager? Even in SQL Server 2008 (don't know about 2005, I didn't have the "pleasure" of using SSIS back then) it supported text qualified data, so there was "no fix" in 2016 that you are referencing.

Comment: Can you also include a sample of the CSV in question? As literal text, not formatted as a markdown table

Comment: is that even a valid csv? i think they're supposed to be escaped by an extra pair of quotes

Comment: i tried with ssms 18.6 and it failed there too, i don't think the sql server version is relevant here, but it failed on 2022 as well. The issue is the bad file IMO. I tried a java csv lib, and it actually imported the row without inner quotes, so something bad is obviously going on. `"GEORGE ""Geo"" LEWIS" "345 Tree Line Ave"` works correctly. I guess you can try importing file without qualifier set and the manually strip it out, your mileage may vary...

Comment: In truth you should really be using a qualifier that **doesn't** appear in your data; it doesn't have to be double quotes (`"`). Normally, however, a text qualifier is used when you have a delimiter that also appears in your data, so the *real* solution is use a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data. It's why, personally, I often use something like (double) pipe (`|`) delimited files, as I know that such character(s) won't appear in my data. (Though text qualifiers are something a necessary evil if you also have data within things like line breaks as well.)

Comment: *.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are missing completely.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, and enforce data quality.

Comment: Seems like your "CSV" file isn't really CSV format. When fields contain delimiter characters they need to be escaped with doubling, i.e.: instead of `"GEORGE "Geo" LEWIS"` the file should contain `"GEORGE ""Geo"" LEWIS"`

Comment: This is just a sample of data that we are getting from our client.  We typically have them go back and replace double quotes with another character when present in the data but wanted to see if this was still possible to import 'as is'.